# creating archon via plain string at ViewComponent and then render by Html.Raw()

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I'm creating navigation by `ViewComponent` at the code behind instead of by `razor view`. The code is generating a string and then using `@Html.Raw(Model.msg)` to render navigation.

`nav += "<a class=\"text-light\" href=\"" + v.Controller.ToLower() + RouteUrl.Slash + v.Value + "\"> " + v.DisplayName + "</a>";`

it's rendering - `<a class="text-light" href="sklep/rowery"> Rowery</a>`
 and I'm going to `http://localhost:55830/sklep/rowery`

for now everything it's ok.

when I wanna go somewhere else using my navigation on the next page, browser shows me the url:
`http://localhost:55830/sklep/sklep/rowery`
but its rendering corect `<a class="text-light" href="sklep/rowery"> Rowery</a>`

**question:** how to prevent such behavior?

**PS:** I do some additional testing and when I'm creating archon in razor view and using `asp-controller=""` and `asp-action=""` everything is ok.

**PS2** creating plain string with `<a asp-controller=\"" + v.Controller.ToLower() + "\" asp-action=\"" + v.Value + "\">`
render - `<a class="text-light" asp-controller="sklep" asp-action="rowery">Rowery</a>` - so it dosent work

I can't rewrite ViewComponent now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do't really know why the `routing system` added the `controller` name to the existing `url`, but to reach my goal, I added a full `url address` to `href` and then the `routing system` stopped mess round